# Custom NSView in NSTableView not showing all subviews

Tags: macos, swift, interface-builder, nstableview, nsview

I'm trying to create a custom `NSView` to display in a column in a view-based `NSTableView`. The view contains 2 subviews, an `NSTextField` and an `NSButton`. I want the button to stay the width set by the constraints, and the textfield to resize when the `NSView` is resized. Below is a small animation showing the `NSView` and its subviews, and the constraints I created.

[image: Creating constraints]

As you can see, resizing the `NSView` works as expected.

Now, when displaying this custom `NSView` in an `NSTableView`, it looks as if the button just disappears, and resizing the column makes the textfield resize with it (the 'Category' column).

[image: Button is gone]

The coded used to create the `NSView` in `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row`:

```swift
let identifier = tableColumn!.identifier

if identifier == "Category" {
    var view = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(identifier, owner: self) as? TableCategoryView

    if view == nil {
        view = TableCategoryView(frame: tableView.frame)
        view!.identifier = identifier
    }

    return view
 }
```

The strange thing is, when there are no constraints on the 2 views, the button and textfield are both happily displayed inside the column, but they then of course don't resize with the table column width.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** It looks like something else is wrong. The `NSView` itself isn't resizing at all with the table column.

Comment: Did you set the NSTableView view-based?

Comment: Yes, the NSTableView's Content Mode is set to View Based.

Comment: Looks like your table view is cell-based, and your custom nsview-subclass doesn't used by the delegate methods. Did you try to enable breakpoints inside the `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row` method?

Comment: Yes. The method is called and views are returned from it. The other columns are also created using that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `TableCategoryView` is your new class and it is subclassed from `NSView` and shall replace the `NSTableCellView` you get when creating (in IB) a view based `NSTableView`. If you really want to create your own TableCellView it should be a direct subclass of `NSTableCellView` not `NSView`.

But in your case (add a button to the  TableCellView) you do not need to create a new class. The existing TableCellView object already has a TextField (a property) with the name `textField`. Then simply drag (means: add) a button into the existing TableCellView (resize it and set the constraints) and drag a link from the button to a corresponding method in the delegate of the TableView. In the "corresponding method" you can ask for the clicked row and column and identify the click button. I did so for a TableView and for me it works well.

Comment: Yes, you are exactly right, I was completely going about it the wrong way. Constraints on the subviews work now too. I did create a subclass of `NSTableCellView` to see if I could make it work, and everything works great now. Thanks!